# how to migrate data from Magento 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, database, ce-1.9.2.4, magento2-migration-tool

I am using Magento 2.0.7 and installed Data Migration Tool. I have found that there are no option to migrate data from magento 1.9.2.4 also I have tried to use [ubertheme migration tool](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-tool/) but getting below error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key
>   'PRIMARY'. The SQL statement executed was: `` INSERT INTO `store` (`website_id`, `group_id`, `sort_order`, `is_active`, `store_id`, `code`, `name`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6) ``

Can anyone help me to fix this issue or suggest any better solution to migrate the data? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why there is no option to migrate data from 1.9.2.4 ? DMT works from 1.6.0.0 -> 1.9.2.4

Comment: I have edit my question. It Magento 2.0.7 and in DMT 2.0.7 there is no option to migrate form 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the Data Migration Tool has a network access to connect to Magento 1 and Magento 2 databases. Open ports in your firewall.
2. Stop all activity in the Magento 1.x Admin Panel (except for order management, such as shipping, creating invoice, credit memos etc.)

> NOTE: Activity cannot resume until your Magento 2 store goes live.

3. Stop all Magento 1.x cron jobs.
4. Use the migration tool to migrate settings and websites.
5. Copy your Magento 1.x media files to Magento 2.0. (You must copy these manually from /media to /pub/media)
6. Use Data Migration Tool to migrate your data from Magento 1 database to Magento 2 database. If some of your extensions have data you want to migrate, you might need to install these extensions adapted for Magento 2. In case the extensions have a different structure in Magento 2 database, use the mapping files provided with the Data Migration Tool.
7. Use the magento indexer:reindex command to reindex all indexers.
8. Thoroughly test your Magento 2.0 site.

More details on : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate-data.html

I hope this helps you !!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your local database.
2. Search for "store".
3. Delete the "Main Store" having website_id=1
4. Clear cache.
   And you are done with this error